# Paste one PDF document in second

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have two PDF documents: PDF-a and PDF-b. 
In first file I have some kind of placeholder - in this place i'd like to paste whole PDF-b. 
I can merge two documents by PdfVeryDenseMergeTool from iText. I thought I might split PDF-a at first, and after merge firt part of PDF-a file with PDF-b and finally merge it witch second part of PDF-a file, but every examples of pdf splitting i found  was about spliting page by page, and my placeholder can be on anywhere of any page.

I looking for solution in Java.